# when I check if valid JWT token in react private route

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, promise

I face problem when change state in redux

check on token

```
  axios.get(VALIDATE_TOKEN_URL, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer token` } })
        .then(response =>{
            dispatch(setIsLogin(response?.data?.status))
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            dispatch(setIsLogin(false))
        })
```

and in private route

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
const { isLogin } = useSelector(state => state.isLogin)


const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(isAuth())


    return isLogin ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;

};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

but its need time before change state to true
how I can handle it

Comment: There is a third state to model besides "user is logged in" and "user is not logged in". You could call it "user login pending" or "determine auth status" for example. Use a separate boolean flag to track wether you can already know if the user is logged in or not. Also you probably don't want to `dispatch(isAuth())` on every re-render.

Comment: I save token in Cookies when user login
but I want protected the route by check if token is still valid

Comment: Yes, so until you have verified with the backend that the token is still valid, your app is in this third state "verifying token" (or however you want to name it). Modelling this third state explicitly elegantly solves your problem.